# Symfony 3.1 Getting Id from another entity in a form modifier

Tags: symfony

I have this in a form builder:

```
        $form->add('region', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Regions',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($country_2a) {

                                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                        ->where('s.countryId= :country_id')
                                        ->setParameter('country_id', $country_2a)
                                        ->addOrderBy('s.name');
            }
        ));
```

The case is that in the entity Regions I have the country_id but I receive the country_2a, then before running the createBuilder I need to search in the entity Countries which is the id for the code_2a.

I have declared in the entities this relations:

```
Countries Entity:

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Regions", mappedBy="country_id")
 */
private $regions;


public function __construct() {
    $this->regions = new ArrayCollection();
}

Regions Entity:

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Countries", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryId;
```

I don't know how to manage to use this relationship between entities, I've tried a JOIN LEFT and a subselect but nothing worked.

Perhaps my problem is that I need to access to the country entity but the $er is connected to the Regions entity, or how to create an createQueryBuilder sentence to exploit the relationship shown.

Any suggestion?.

Comment: Hi Carlos. Does the variable "$country_2a" represent a Country Entity? Or does it represent the country_id link in the Regions Entity? It's not very clear from your code. Also in your `createQueryBuilder` you use the alias `'s'`, but this is confusing, since the EntityType is AppBundle:Regions. So instead I would use an alias of `'r'` where the `'r'` represents 'Region'.

Answer (score 0):

you Regions Entity should be like this:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Countries", inversedBy="regions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $countryId;
```

Try that change.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. I'm still struggling with the original question: How can I recup the regions of the selected country?.